# PHPMailer: Handling "recipients failed"

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm sending e-mails via PHPMailer in a loop but if for some reason I send to an address not accepted by the receiving server PHPMailer throws an exception and the script dies. I would like my script to continue and handle this bad address in another way.

Any ideas on how to avoid PHPMailer dying on exceptions?

```
try
{
    // prep
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SetFrom(email_reply_adress, email_from_name);
    $mail->Host = email_smtp_host;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = email_username; 
    $mail->Password = email_password;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddReplyTo(email_reply_adress, email_from_name);

    //
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE sent = '0'";
    $result = @mysql_query($query);
    while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        // receiver
        $mail->AddAddress($row['email']);

        // subject
        $mail->Subject = utf8_decode($row['subject']);

        // build mail
        $mail->Body = utf8_decode(stripslashes($row['content']));

        // send it                  
        if($mail->Send())
        {
            // stats
            $sent = "UPDATE table SET sentdate = now(), sent = '1' WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'";
            mysql_query($sent);
        }

        // clean up lists
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    }
}
catch(phpmailerException $e)
{
    echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
}
```

Comment: Show some code and we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to place the code that throws the exception into a try..catch block... going on a lot of guess work as to what your code looks like but this should give you the idea.

```
foreach($emails as $email){
      try{
          // do your work
      } catch (Exception $e){
          echo $email." not sent .. Error = ".$e->getMessage()."\n";
          // perform logging and so other meaningful stuff here. 
      }
}
```

Comment: move the try catch into the while loop .... you are catching outside of it so it can't recover

Comment: Hmm. That only throws a lot of "SMTP server error: 5.5.1 Error: nested MAIL command".